# SQL - When Case should not check for result when no case matches?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, case-when

I want no results for null when nothing matches

```
select t.range as [PriceRange], count(1) as [BooksCount]
from (
  select case  
    when  Offer > 3  and offer < 5 
    then 'Criteria1'
    when offer >= 5 then 'Criteria2'
    
    END as range    
  from BookDetailsMaster) t
group by t.range
```

This query return value for null range also, because of which it is taking long time to execute. I want it should not search anything in database if no case matches.

If I apply a filter `where t.range is not null` it is not returning the null values but the query is taking long, so I am doubting it is still checking for no match criteria but while returning result it is not returning that value.

```
Id Offer
1    2
2    4
3    5
4    6
5    7
6    1

PriceRange  BooksCount
-------------------------
Criteria1   1
Criteria2   3
```

The doubt is it is also making query for a null criteria

Comment: Please share sample data to reproduce the issue. Share the (create table + insert data) scripts.

Comment: It is certainly possible to group by a `NULL` value...`NULL` can be its own group.  You should add sample data to explain the problem here.

Comment: Why not add a where to the query which excludes those cases.

Comment: You can only filter these in a `WHERE`, either in your inner query (though you say that's too complex), or in your outer query (though you say this affects performance too much). These are your two options, you may be able to get some help with the performance issue if you ask a new question about that.

Comment: `so I am doubting it is still checking for no match criteria but while returning result it is not returning that value.` It is `no doubt` that in your case database do check for no-matching-criteria. Your `CASE` is not a `WHERE`, and `CASE` only apply to returning data, not filtering data from database to return to you. `WHERE` do that.

Answer (score 4):

You should do this simple condition

```
SELECT t.RANGE AS [PriceRange], COUNT(1) AS [BooksCount]
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    CASE  
        WHEN  Offer > 3  AND offer < 5  THEN 'Criteria1'
        WHEN offer >= 5 THEN 'Criteria2'
    END AS RANGE    
  FROM BookDetailsMaster
  WHERE offer > 3
) t
GROUP BY t.RANGE;
```

Comment: The query will be complex enough to put everything in where clause

Comment: @Manjay_TBAG that query, with a simple filter, do exactly what you want  with minimum effort and best performance `I want it should not search anything in database if no case matches.`. But if you mean that you just simplify your case and your real query is not what you post , you should describe your case and your real query, so that we could see what we could do for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use where then you can try below option

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (OFFER >3 AND OFFER<5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [BooksCount], 'Criteria1'  [PriceRange]
FROM BookDetailsMaster
UNION 
SELECT SUM(CASE  WHEN (offer >= 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 'Criteria2'
FROM BookDetailsMaster
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already defining `range` in a subquery.  Just use it for filtering in the outer query:

```
select t.range as PriceRange, count(1) as BooksCount
from (select (case when  Offer > 3 and offer < 5 then 'Criteria1'
                   when offer >= 5 then 'Criteria2'        
              end) as range    
      from BookDetailsMaster
     ) t
where t.range is not null
group by t.range
```